# Rails Active Record Query Total leaves on a weekday

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The scenario is that there is hotel and it has so many employees. now employees can apply for the leaves.

Leaves table have the start and end date column suppose a employee takes leave from 5, December to 15 December than start date will be 5 December and end date will be 15 December.

How can I get the total leaves in 2017 on particular weekday like on Monday?

Found the solution:

```
def calculate_weekdays
count_weekday = {}
(0..6).to_a.select{|t| count_weekday[t]=0 }
Event.all.each do |event|
  start_date, end_date = event.start_time, event.end_time
  result = ( start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date ).to_a.select { |k| count_weekday[k.wday]=count_weekday[k.wday]+1}
end
return count_weekday
end
```

Comment: You need to fetch all leaves in an array with day of date when employee take leave. And then we can filter data according to your need. Because in database you did not save data of particular day so I dont think it can be solve by any sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use gem [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

With a query like:

```
Leave.where( ... ).group_by_day_of_week(:start_date).count
```